# How to configure Presto

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, presto

I have installed presto on my cluster in order to perform some queries. I have 4 nodes with 16GB of RAM. I have followed the steps into configuring presto but when i ran a query it takes forever, much more time than the same query on Hive. So i think i have something wrong in my configurations.

I think maybe i the wrong values on my node.properties file in the properties 
query.max-memory and query.max-memory-per-node. Whats the correct values for this properties taking in account that i have 16GB of RAM in each node?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have found the correct properties you may need to tweak. But there is no "correct" value... It really depends on your data + queries. Could you provide a general summary of the data set and types of queries you're running?

Comment: in This moment i wanted to run some of the TPC-DS Benchmarking

Comment: what scale factor are you using? Do you have a few example queries that are not working as expected? Or is it all of them?

Comment: im using 10, 30, 50 and 100GBm in order to perform a benchmark...the most critical case that i have is query 95... which im only able to run on the scale factor of 10GB (https://github.com/hortonworks/hive-testbench/blob/hive14/sample-queries-tpcds/query95.sql) the others kill all the workers during the query execution